# How to connect install and connect to a GUI SUSE on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, opensuse, suse

I just installed an EC2 SUSE server on AWS and everything is fine.

Now, my client wants to connect to the server with a GUI since he doesnt know how to work on terminal. How can I install a GUI like GNOME on SUSE?

Answer (score 0):

YaST allows you to configure remote access to a graphical display manager. This display manager is then accessed via the VNC protocol, for example. It certainly all depends on how you, as an admin of that instance, want to expose this instance to the outside world. And it depends on how the client can and wants to access the instance from his own environment.

Once the connection is established, the display manager allows a login and starts the desktop environment. It will all look and behave like on an ordinary PC or laptop. Sure, it will obviously lack things like 3D or whatever effects a given desktop environment may want to use to show fancy effects. Either such things are notable slow, or they are not shown at all because the remote connection is discovered in some way.

Comment: How do o configure this VNC? Does it have to be an AWS VNC? I installed xming and configured it with localhost IP, but i think it is not right because no GUI Is show

Comment: As I said, use `YaST2` to configure it. Make sure `yast2-network.rpm` is installed (`zypper se -snt package yast2-network`). In the "network services tab" is something with "admin of remote systems (VNC)", which allows to enable remote access to the system that runs YaST2.